# How to create custom validation rule for 4 combinedly unique columns

Tags: php, laravel

Since Laravel's default [`unique:tablename`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#rule-unique) validation rule allows only two columns; in scenarios where more than two columns are unique, it directly throws the `QueryException` with [SQLSTATE errorcode 23000](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/error-messages-server.html#error_er_dup_key). As a temporary workaround I am catching the exception and throwing a warning like this:

```
try{
    //My query that might throw an exception for a duplicate entry
} catch (\Exception $e){
    return $e->getCode() == 23000 ?
           redirect()->back()->with('warning','Duplicate entry') :
           redirect()->back()->with('error','Unknown Error Occurred');
}
```

The problem is, for every other scenarios where the errorcode is not 23000, I will only see an error message `Unknown Error Occurred` instead of [Whoops](https://github.com/filp/whoops). Clearly, debugging will be a nightmare.

So I looked for alternatives. I had to pick one of two options: a) Use a [third party package](https://github.com/felixkiss/uniquewith-validator) or, b) Create a [custom validation rule](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#custom-validation-rules)

I chose option b. But I am struggling with how I can construct one myself. When I looked at an example (for one-time inline rule):

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'title' => [
       'required',
       'max:255',
        function($attribute, $value, $fail) {
            if ($value === 'foo') {
                return $fail($attribute.' is invalid.');
            }
        },
    ],
]);
```

...I realized that the rule can be applied to a single attribute and value only. But I have 4 attributes and values to check if they are indeed a unique entry. How can I do that?

Comment: Try with [after-validation-hook](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#after-validation-hook). Check for unique for all 4 fields in the after validation hook.

Comment: Okay, I am trying. But is the `somethingElseIsInvalid()` method a placeholder method or does it really have a purpose? Couldn't find it in the API doc.

Comment: How do you want to implement unique rule? Can you give an example?

Comment: Something like `multicolumnunique:tablename,column1,column2,column3,column4`

Comment: Then you may use multiple unique rule. like , `unique:table1,column1|unique:table1,field2|unique:table1,field3`. Or in the after validation hook, where you have to implement the logic for unique for 4 fields in the place of `somethingElseIsInvalid()`

Comment: @ab_ab I think you've got me wrong. They are "combinedly unique". Your approach of validation only checks the uniqueness for individual fields not altogether.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use like this,

```
public function store(Request $req)
{
    $column1 = $req->input('column1');
    $column2 = $req->input('column2');
    $column3 = $req->input('column3');
    $column4 = $req->input('column4');


    $whereData = [
        ['column1', $column1],
        ['column2', $column2],
        ['column3', $column3],
        ['column4', $column4]
    ];

    $count = DB::table('yourtablename')->where($whereData)
                                ->count();

    if($count > 0){
        // The combined is not unique
        //send error message
    }else{
        //do whatever u need
    }

}
```

You may implement this in `AppServiceProvider`'s boot method also.

Add this code to your boot method:

```
Validator::extend('uniqueofFourColumns', function ($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {

    $whereData = [
        ['column1', $value],
        ['column2', $parameters[0]],
        ['column3', $parameters[1]],
        ['column4', $parameters[2]]
    ];

    $count = DB::table('yourtablename')->where($whereData)->count();

    return $count === 0;
});
```

Then u may use `uniqueofFourColumns` this rule wherever u need:

```
'column1' => 'uniqueofFourColumns:'.{{$request->column2}}.', '.{{$request->column3}}.', '.{{$request->column4}}
```

Comment: That's not really a rule, that's what I intend to do in a validation rule. But I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Thanks @arun. Is there any way to make columns dynamic as well? What if I am not using the same column names for each table?

Comment: To make it even more dynamic, may I suggest an edit? Let's send the first parameter as the $tablename: `'column1' => uniqueofFourColumns:yourtablename'.{{$request->column2}}.', '.{{$request->column3}}.', '....` And then in the boot method: `$count = DB::table($tablename)->where($whereData)->count();`