# Laravel unique validation on multiple columns

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I have 2 columns in table servers.

I have columns `ip` and `hostname`.

I have validation:

```
'data.ip' => ['required', 'unique:servers,ip,'.$this->id]
```

This working only for column `ip`. But how to do that it would work and for column `hostname`?

I want validate data.ip with columns `ip` and `hostname`.
Because can be duplicates in columns ip and hostname, when user write ip.

Comment: do u need to valiate combinely unique for ip and hostname?

Comment: @arun Yes. I have 1 form for ip. When user write ip, I need validate this ip in column ip and in column hostname.. if exists

Comment: there is no inbuilt validation like what u wanted. u may extend it, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50095328/how-to-create-custom-validation-rule-for-4-combinedly-unique-columns/50096190#50096190

Comment: @arun, But I can do this: `'data.ip' => ['required', 'unique:servers,ip,'.$this->id, 'unique:servers,hostname']` ?

Comment: Do another field validation seperately, `'data.hostname' => ['required', 'unique:servers,hostname']`

Comment: @arun no, I don't have input hostname. I need validate ip input in two columns

Comment: Try this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33855787/laravel-validation-unique-on-two-columns

Comment: Do you want check separately or combined ?  Update your question with all logic ?

Comment: @C2486 updated question..

Comment: I just have a question about how you fixed the problem, in the answer you checked you have the line   Rule::unique('servers')->where(function ($query) use($ip,$hostname) and i wonder if you defined these variables ($ip,$hostname) somewhere before using them?

Comment: Referenece Link working on 5.5

https://laravel.io/forum/11-03-2015-laravel-unique-validation-on-multiple-columns-for-unique-relations

Comment: 'ip' => 'required|unique:servers,ip,NULL,id,deleted_at,NULL,another_column,'.$this->value1.',another_column,'.$this->value2

Comment: @RedEyez For new visitors, you can get them from the request itself (`$this->ip`) instead of using `use($ip,$hostname)`.

Answer (score 109, accepted):

You can use [`Rule::unique`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#rule-unique) to achieve your validation rule

```
$messages = [
    'data.ip.unique' => 'Given ip and hostname are not unique',
];

Validator::make($data, [
    'data.ip' => [
        'required',
        Rule::unique('servers')->where(function ($query) use($ip,$hostname) {
            return $query->where('ip', $ip)
            ->where('hostname', $hostname);
        }),
    ],
],
$messages
);
```

edit: Fixed message assignation

Comment: absolutely perfect solution, but need to also update operation.

Comment: i tried something similar but I got undefined variable when using " use($variable1, $variable2) ". do i have to define those somewhere?

Comment: Use it this way:
`
$text = $this->request->text;
$branch_id = $this->request->branch_id;
$validator = \Validator::make($this->request->all(), array( 
         'text' => [
           'required',
           Rule::unique('cpl_tax')->where(function ($query) use($text, $branch_id) {
               return $query->where('text', $text)
                        ->where('branch_id', $branch_id);
                    }),
                ], 
            ));
`
@RedEyez

Comment: @RazibAlMamun For update use this

`$text = $this->request->text;
        $branch_id = $this->request->branch_id;
        $tax_id = $this->request->tax_id;
        $validator = \Validator::make($this->request->all(), array( 
            'text' => [
                'required',
                Rule::unique('cpl_tax')->where(function ($query) use($tax_id, $text, $branch_id) {
                    return $query->where('text', $text)
                    ->where('branch_id', $branch_id)->where('tax_id', '!=', $tax_id);
                }),
            ],  
        ));`

Comment: For update use ingore. `->ignore($serverid);` see the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/58028505/9978078

Answer (score 47):

The following will work on the create

```
'data.ip' => ['required', 'unique:servers,ip,'.$this->id.',NULL,id,hostname,'.$request->input('hostname')]
```

and the following for the update

```
'data.ip' => ['required', 'unique:servers,ip,'.$this->id.','.$request->input('id').',id,hostname,'.$request->input('hostname')]
```

I'm presuming that `id` is your primary key in the table. Substitute it for your environment.

---

The (undocumented) format for the unique rule is:

> *table*[,*column*[,*ignore value*[,*ignore column*[,*where column*,*where value*]...]]]

Multiple "where" conditions can be specified, but only equality can be checked. A closure (as in the accepted answer) is needed for any other comparisons.

Comment: I use custom request. And for store and for update I use the same request.

Comment: You would need to elaborate regarding what you mean by custom request. Then for the update and store it is ok to use the same request, however if the request contains the rules you will have an issue on the update if you do not ignore the entry into your database with the current primary key.

Comment: What if value contains comma?

Comment: I doubt that `$request->input('id')` is necessary. This works for me `['column_1' => 'required|unique:TableName,column_1,' . $this->id . ',id,colum_2,' . $this->column_2]` for both create and update.

Comment: This is exactly what i was looking for, detail explanation and example is missing on the official docs!

Comment: For me this is not working for update. I got this `  "title" => "required|min:2|max:255|unique:terms,title,20,id,type,listing-category"`. I had no entry rather then id 20 with same title. And I am trying to edit the same entry, I mean id with 20. But it is throwing me error instead of updating. Although for create it is working fine

Comment: I need to check for unique condition where type in terms table is listing-category

Comment: I feel lucky to come across this solution! Surprised why it is not in official document.

Comment: A heads up, this doesn't seem to be working in Laravel 10, anymore. I am now getting "undefined array key 3", from a Vendor file that decodes the validation rules. It seems like the "unique" validation rule doesn't support more than three arguments, anymore.

Answer (score 21):

**Table**

> server

**Field**

> - id `primary key`
> - ip `should be unique with hostname`
> - hostname `should be unique with ip`

Here I validate for Ip and the hostname should be unique.

```
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;

$ip = '192.168.0.1';
$host = 'localhost';
```

### While Create

```
Validator::make($data, [
    'ip' => [
        'required',
         Rule::unique('server')->where(function ($query) use($ip,$host) {
           return $query->where('ip', $ip)->where('hostname', $host);
         });
    ],
]);
```

### While Update

Add ignore after `RULE`

```
Validator::make($data, [
    'ip' => [
        'required',
         Rule::unique('server')->where(function ($query) use($ip,$host) {
           return $query->where('ip', $ip)->where('hostname', $host);
         })->ignore($serverid);
    ],
]);
```

Comment: It is ignoring where condition in my case, I guess, while updating. I dd() the condition and got this.

`Illuminate\Validation\Rules\Unique {#1871 ▼
  #ignore: "10"
  #idColumn: "id"
  #table: "term"
  #column: "NULL"
  #wheres: array:1 [▼
    0 => array:2 [▼
      "column" => "type"
      "value" => "list-cat"
    ]
  ]
  #using: []
}`

But not working at all while updating.

Comment: There is a category with the same name in table. But the type is different

Comment: Note: i am using Laravel 5.8

Answer (score 21):

This works for me for both create and update.

```
[
     'column_1' => 'required|unique:TableName,column_1,' . $this->id . ',id,colum_2,' . $this->column_2
]
```

Note: tested in Laravel 6.

Comment: I use one method to insert and update, this work for me, and very simple. Thanks O Connor !

Answer (score 20):

## Laravel 5.6 and above

#### Validation in the controller

The primary key (in my case) is a combination of two columns (**name**, **guard_name**)

I validate their uniqueness by using the **Rule** class both on **create** and on **update** method of my controller (**PermissionsController**)

---

**PermissionsController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Permission;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class PermissionsController extends Controller
{

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        request()->validate([

            'name'        => 'required|max:255',

            'guard_name'  => [

                'required', 

                Rule::unique('permissions')->where(function ($query) use ($request) {

                    return $query
                        ->whereName($request->name)
                        ->whereGuardName($request->guard_name);
                }),
            ],
        ],
        [
            'guard_name.unique' => __('messages.permission.error.unique', [

                'name'              => $request->name, 
                'guard_name'        => $request->guard_name
            ]),
        ]);

        Permission::create($request->all());

        flash(__('messages.permission.flash.created'))->success();

        return redirect()->route('permission.index');
    }


    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     */
    public function update(Request $request, Permission $permission)
    {
        request()->validate([

            'name'        => 'required|max:255',

            'guard_name'  => [

                'required', 

                Rule::unique('permissions')->where(function ($query) use ($request, $permission) {

                    return $query
                        ->whereName($request->name)
                        ->whereGuardName($request->guard_name)
                        ->whereNotIn('id', [$permission->id]);
                }),
            ],
        ],
        [
            'guard_name.unique' => __('messages.permission.error.unique', [

                'name'              => $request->name, 
                'guard_name'        => $request->guard_name
            ]),
        ]);

        $permission->update($request->all());

        flash(__('messages.permission.flash.updated'))->success();

        return redirect()->route('permission.index');
    }
}
```

Notice in the update method i added an additional query constraint [ **whereNotIn('id', [$permission->id])** ] to ignore the current model.

---

**resources/lang/en/messages.php**

```
<?php

return [

    'permission' => [

        'error' => [
            'unique' => 'The combination [":name", ":guard_name"] already exists',
        ],

        'flash' => [
            'updated' => '...',
            'created' => '...',
        ],
    ]
]
```

---

The flash() method is from the [laracasts/flash](https://github.com/laracasts/flash) package.

Comment: absolutely perfect solution

Comment: This should definitely be the accepted answer. The inclusion of custom error messages in the language files makes it really flexible and provides perfect feedback. Thanks

Answer (score 10):

**With Form Requests:**

### In StoreServerRequest (for Create)

```
public function rules() {
    'ip' => [
        'required',
         Rule::unique('server')->where(function ($query) {
             $query->where('ip', $this->ip)
                ->where('hostname', $this->host);
         })
    ],
}

public function messages() {
    return [
       'ip.unique' => 'Combination of IP & Hostname is not unique',
    ];
}
```

### In UpdateServerRequest (for Update)

Just Add ignore at the end

```
public function rules() {
    'ip' => [
        'required',
         Rule::unique('server')->where(function ($query) {
             $query->where('ip', $this->ip)
                ->where('hostname', $this->host);
         })->ignore($this->server->id)
    ],
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Try this rule:
`'data.ip' => 'required|unique:servers,ip,'.$this->id.'|unique:servers,hostname,'.$this->id`

Comment: this makes wrong condition and is not equal to `unique(['ip','hostname'])` but it is for `unique('ip'); unique('hostname');` which is different

Answer (score 2):

This is the demo code. It would help you much better. I tried covering both insert and update scenarios.

Inside **app/Http/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php**

```
Validator::extend('uniqueOfMultiple', function ($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator)
    {
        $whereData = [
            [$attribute, $value]
        ];

        foreach ($parameters as $key => $parameter) {

            //At 0th index, we have table name
            if(!$key) continue;

            $arr = explode('-', $parameter);

            if($arr[0] == 'except') {
                $column = $arr[1];
                $data = $arr[2];

                $whereData[] = [$column, '<>', $data];
            } else {
                $column = $arr[0];
                $data = $arr[1];

                $whereData[] = [$column, $data];
            }
        }

        $count = DB::table($parameters[0])->where($whereData)->count();
        return $count === 0;
    });
```

Inside **app/Http/Requests/Something/StoreSometing.php**

```
/**
 * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'name' => 'required|max:225|uniqueOfMultiple:menus,location_id-' . $this->get('location_id', 'NULL') . ',language_id-' . $this->get('language_id', 1),
        'location_id' => 'required|exists:menu_location,id',
        'order' => 'digits_between:0,10'
    ];
}
```

Inside **app/Http/Requests/Something/UpdateSomething.php**

```
/**
 * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'name' => 'required|max:225|uniqueOfMultiple:menus,location_id-' . $this->get('location_id', 'NULL') . ',language_id-' . $this->get('language_id', 'NULL') . ',except-id-' . $this->route('id', 'NULL'),
        'location_id' => 'required|exists:menu_location,id',
        'order' => 'digits_between:0,10'
    ];
}
```

Inside **resources/lang/en/validation.php**

```
'unique_of_multiple' => 'The :attribute has already been taken under it\'s parent.',
```

Here in this code, the custom validation used is `uniqueOfMultiple`. The first argument passed is the table_name i.e `menus` and all other arguments are column_name and are comma-separated. The columns are used here, `name` (primary column), `location_id`, `language_id` and one except-for column for the update case, `except-id`. The value passed for all three is `-` separated.

Comment: I have published a laravel package for the same. Do check it out https://packagist.org/packages/ankitsinghdalal/laravel-unique-on-multiple

Comment: I have published a laravel package for the same. Do check it out https://packagist.org/packages/ankitsinghdalal/laravel-unique-on-multiple

Answer (score 2):

This works for me for both create and update.

in your ServerUpdateRequest or ServerCreateRequest class

```
public function rules()
{            
    return [
       'column_1' => 'required|unique:TableName,column_1,' . $this->id . ',id,colum_2,' . $this->column_2 . ',colum_3,' . $this->column_3,
    ];
}
```

This command run background a aggregate Sql like this

```
select
   count(*) as aggregate 
from 
  `TableName` 
where 
  `column_1` = <postedColumn1Value>  
   and `id` <> idValue 
   and `column_2` = <postedColumn2Value> 
   and `column_3` = <postedColumn3Value>
```

tested in Laravel 9. and it works

Note: if you want to see background sql for debugging (For example, to check if the request values are empty[$this->]) , especially you have to write wrong code, For example, you may enter a filed name incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

The following code worked nicely for me at Laravel 8

**Create:**

```
'required|unique:TableName,column_1,' . $this->column_1 . ',id,colum_2,' . $this->column_2,
```

*Example:*

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $union = auth()->user()->union_id;
    $request->validate([
        'holding_no' => 'required|integer|unique:holding_taxes,holding_no,' . $request->holding_no . ',id,union_id,' . $union,
    ]);   
}
```

**Update:**

```
'required|unique:TableName,column_1,' . $this->id . ',id,colum_2,' . $this->column_2,
```

*Example:*

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $union = auth()->user()->union_id;
    $request->validate([
        'holding_no' => 'required|unique:holding_taxes,holding_no,' . $id . ',id,union_id,'.$union,
    ]);   
}
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing, but this answer looks the same as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50350625/1255289) from 4 years earlier. As well, answers should be tailored to match the question, including variable and attribute names.

Comment: @miken32 I know but I tried to make it more specific that helps to understand easily. Thanks

Comment: plus one because it helped me to find out the exact answer for the L8, just what I was looking for.

Comment: @Armin.G Its my pleasure

Answer (score 1):

This code works in Laravel 9 to make two columns unique together

**Create Request**

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
                'column1' => [
                'string',
                'required',
                Rule::unique('table_name')
                     ->where('column2', $this->column2)
                ],
            ];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

for me laravel 8 this works

```php
$req->validate([
    'house_no' => [
        Rule::unique('house')
          ->where('house_no', $req->input('house_no'))
          ->where('ward_no', $req->input('ward_no'))
    ],
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution with call back query

```
  Rule::unique('users')->where(fn ($query) => $query->where(['project_id'=> request()->project_id, 'code'=> request()->code ])),
```

Answer (score -2):

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
         $this->validate($request, [
            'first_name' => 'required|regex:/^[\pL\s\-]+$/u|max:255|unique:contacts,first_name, NULL,id,first_name,'.$request->input('last_name','id'),
            'last_name'=>'required|regex:/^[\pL\s\-]+$/u|max:255|unique:contacts,last_name',
            'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:contacts,email',
            'job_title'=>'required',
            'city'=>'required',
            'country'=>'required'],
            [
             'first_name.regex'=>'Use Alphabets Only',
             'email.unique'=>'Email is Already Taken.Use Another Email',
             'last_name.unique'=>'Contact Already Exist!. Try Again.',
            ]
        );
```