# Database data field check before Data insertion

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, laravel-5

I have a data coming from the HTML Page. And i want to check whether the date and the place values already exists. If they exists, it should throw an error saying Data is already present, if those date and place data is not there it should allow the user to save it.

Here is the code which i have written to save it,

```
public function StoreSampling(Request $request)
{
  $date = Carbon::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', $request->input('date'))->format('Y-m-d');

  $doctorname = Input::get('doctorselected');
  $product = Input::get('product');
  $product= implode(',', $product);
  $quantity = Input::get('qty');
  $quantity =implode(',',$quantity);
  $representativeid = Input::get('representativeid');
  //Store all the parameters.
  $samplingOrder = new   SamplingOrder();
  $samplingOrder->date = $date;
  $samplingOrder->doctorselected = $doctorname;
  $samplingOrder->products = $product;
  $samplingOrder->quantity = $quantity;
  $samplingOrder->representativeid = $representativeid;
  $samplingOrder->save();
  return redirect()->back()->with('success',true);
}
```

I searched some of the Stack over flow pages. And came across finding the existence through the ID And here is the sample,

```
$count = DB::table('teammembersall')
    ->where('TeamId', $teamNameSelectBoxInTeamMembers)
    ->where('UserId', $userNameSelectBoxInTeamMembers)
    ->count();

if ($count > 0){
    // This user already in a team
    //send error message
} else {
    DB::table('teammembersall')->insert($data);
}
```

But i want to compare the date and the place. And if they are not present, i want to let the user to save it. Basically trying to stop the duplicate entries.

Please help me with this.

Comment: And what exactly stops you from adapting the example you quoted? `$count = DB::table('SamplingOrder')->where('date', $date)->where('place', $place)`

Comment: Please improve your question as the`place` attribute is not mentioned anywhere.

Comment: @YahyaUddin: Yup, Bymistake added another method from the controller. Got it resolved. Thanks for looking into it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to modify your query to something like this:

```
$userAlreadyInTeam = SamplingOrder::where('date', $date)
    ->where('place', $place) // I'm not sure what the attribute name is for this as not mentioned in question
    // any other conditions
    ->exists();

if (userAlreadyInTeam) {
    // Handle error
} else {
    // Create
}
```

You do not need to use `count()` as your only trying to determine existence.

Also consider adding a multi column `unique` attribute to your database, to guarantee that you don't have a member with the same data and place.

Comment: Thanks for the simplest answer. Choose this among all the others. Thanks for taking a time for the resolution. Solved my requirement.

Comment: @NagendraBhat Please mark this answer as correct if this solved your issue

Comment: Yup. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

There are very good helper functions for this called `firstOrNew` and `firstOrCreate`, the latter will directly create it, while the first one you will need to explicitly call `save`. So I would go with the following:

```
$order = SamplingOrder::firstOrNew([
  'date' => $date,
  'place' => $place 
], [
   'doctorname'       => Input::get('doctorselected'),
   'product'          => implode(',', Input::get('product')),
   'quantity'         => implode(',',Input::get('qty')),
   'representativeid' => Input::get('representativeid')
]);

if($order->exists()) {
   // throw error
   return;
}

$order->save();
// success
```

Comment: Thanks for taking a time for the resolution. Solved my requirement.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use the [laravel unique validation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#rule-unique) on multiple columns. Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50349775/laravel-unique-validation-on-multiple-columns).
I'm presuming that `id` is your primary key and in the `sampling_orders` table. The validation rule looks like this:

```
'date' => ['unique:sampling_orders,date,'.$date.',NULL,id,place,'.$place]
```

p.s: I do not see any `place` input in your `StoreSampling()`