# Laravel : Handle Integrity constraint violation error and return simplified error message

Tags: php, laravel, error-handling

I have a App where I want the combination of three fields: `rollyear`, `rollfaculty` and `rollno` in a table to be unique. For that, I did the following in the migration file:

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email');
            $table->string('rollyear');
            $table->string('rollfaculty');
            $table->string('rollno');
            $table->unique(['rollyear','rollfaculty','rollno']);
        });
```

This is working as expected but whenever duplicate values are supplied to the specified fields, I get a full page  **Integrity constraint violation** error.
How can I handle this error and give a simplified error message to the user as in following image?[image: Error Message]

Comment: I think the only way to get a verified error is by checking the email address against your database. Although duplicate error returns error code 1062.

Comment: You can handle unique validation gracefully by using Laravel's validator. To validate uniqueness on the three columns use `Rule::unique`, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/50350824/2797224

Answer (score 0):

add validate through jQuery

save this file on your public/js folder

Here's [a link](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.16.0/jquery.validate.min.js/)!

and ad another validation file for register

```
// validate signup form on keyup and submit
$("#addUserForm").validate({
            rules: {
                name:{
                    required:true
                },
                email: {
                    required: true,
                    email: true,
                    remote: {
                        url: "/checkuser",
                        type: "get"
                    }
                },
                password: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 5
                },
                image: {
                    required:true,
                    accept: "jpg|jpeg|png|JPG|JPEG|PNG"
                }
            },
            messages: {
                name: {
                    required:"Please enter a  name"
                },
                email: {
                    required:"Please enter a  email address",
                    email:"Please enter a valid email address",
                    remote:"Email Already Exist"
                },
                password: {
                    required: "Please provide a password",
                    minlength: "Your password must be at least 5 characters long"
                },
                image: {
                    required: "Please provide a profile image",
                    accept: "Please upload only jpg,jpeg,png"
                }
            }
});
```

add /checkuser

```
public function checkUser()
{
    $user = User::where('email', request('email'))->exists();
     if($user){
        return 'false';
     }
     else {
        return 'true';
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please put below code in your controller where you store users details.

```
$chkUniqueEmailId = DB::table('users')->where('email', '=', $request->email)->first();
    if(!empty($chkUniqueEmailId)){
      return redirect()->route('auth.register')->withFlashDanger("This email address already exists.");
    }
```