# Laravel with (And) operator inside validation

Tags: php, laravel, validation, unique, operator-keyword

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'title' => 'required|max:255',
        'type' => 'required|max:255',
        'lang' => 'required|max:255',
        // 'lang' => 'required|max:255|unique:termcondition',
        // 'type' => 'required|max:255||unique:termcondition'
    ];
}
```

- i want to make a validation which is combinig 2 column with (And) operator,
- there is "type" and "lang" columns. so i want to make them unique with (And) operator.
- can somebody help me ... ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50349775/laravel-unique-validation-on-multiple-columns ---- This might help you. :)