# Add unique validation for 3 fields on creationRules in laravel nova resources

Tags: laravel, validation, unique, laravel-nova

While creating the user, I want the adhar_number, phone_number and email as unique in laravel nova.

I tried doing the following,

```
public function fields(Request $request)
    {
        return [
            ID::make()->sortable(),

            Text::make('Adhaar Number')->rules('required'), 

            Text::make('Phone Number')->rules('required'),

            Text::make('Email')->rules('max:255', 'required')
                ->creationRules('unique:users,adhaar_number,phone_number,email'),

        ];
    }
```

The above field definition gives a success message that resource has been created, whereas it should produce error message. In the log file it logs the duplicate entry error.

Comment: Check following answer, https://stackoverflow.com/a/50350824