# How to write a rule to validate that a combination of multiple columns must be unique in Laravel 6, PHP?

Tags: laravel, validation, unique, multiple-columns, rules

Let's say you have a `users` table with the column `email` and email must be unique per user, you can use the following validation rule in Laravel.

```
[
    'email' => 'unique:users,email,' . $user->id,
]
```

In my case, my `users` table looks like following

```
id
email
type
```

For my use case, the combination of `email` and `type` must be unique, which means that `email` can exist more than one time, and so does `type`. But the combination of `email` and `type` must be unique. Desired result looks like following

```
id       email                type
 1       A@mail.com           1    // OK! unique
 2       A@mail.com           2    // OK! unique
 3       B@mail.com           1    // OK! unique
 4       B@mail.com           2    // OK! unique
 5       A@mail.com           1    // NOT OK! already exists with id = 1.
 6       B@mail.com           2    // NOT OK! already exists with id = 4.
```

How to write a rule to validate that a combination of `email` and `type` must be unique in Laravel, PHP, to prevent record with id `5` and `6` from being inserted into database?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel unique validation on multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50349775/laravel-unique-validation-on-multiple-columns)

Comment: I'd handle this at the database level, personally, and catch unique key errors.

Answer (score 0):

The Laravel's unique validation rule does not handle well field combinations as unique. So the best option for you is to implement a [custom validation method or class](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/validation#custom-validation-rules) with a custom query. Probably the closure option would be the simplest to implement (but you need the modified user instance):

```
function ($attribute, $value, $fail) use ($user) {
  $exists = User::where('users.email', $value)
    ->where('users.type', $user->type)
    ->where('users.id', '!=', $user->id)
    ->count();

  if ($exists) {
    $fail($attribute . ' is invalid.');
  }
}
```

If you receive both fields in the request (both type and e-mail), you can look at the solution linked by Caddy DZ in the comments, but I think that's not your case.

Answer (score 0):

Have found some compact solution. This works for me for both create and update.

```
[
    'column_1' => 'required|unique:TableName,column_1,' . $this->id . ',id,colum_2,' . $this->column_2
]
```

Note: tested in Laravel 6.

I did put this answer in another question (Laravel unique validation on multiple columns) of someone else.