# How to validate two column unique where one column is nullable in in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, validation

I have the following database table structure for an `agents` table

```
+--------------------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field                    | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                       | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| first_name               | varchar(255)        | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| phone                    | varchar(255)        | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| active                   | tinyint(1)          | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+--------------------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

the fields `phone` and `active` is having a 2 column unique constraint, meaning only one `phone` should be in the active state at once. the column `active` is a nullable boolean, because if I put `0` for the falsy value then the 2 columns unique constraint will fail if there are two inactive `phone` numbers (since null != null it is working fine on the database level when I manually insert it in database). I hope I am clear here.

**The Problem**

I am trying to set up the validation rules for this feature. So while creating an agent if there is any `active` phone numbers the validation should fail, otherwise, the record should be inserted.

here is my validation rule

```
$request->validate([
   'first_name'=> 'required',
   'active' => 'required',
   'phone' => [
       'required', 
       Rule::unique('delivery_agents')->using(function ($query) use ($request) {
             $query->where('phone', $request->phone)
                 ->where('active', $request->active ? $request->active : null); // explicitly checking against null value or true not 0
       })
    ],
 ]);
```

But the validation rule fails when there is one inactive phone number (ie: `phone` number with `active = null`)

I believe the reason is that the validation rule checks for phone number with `active = null`  and since there is one record like that it throws the validation failed exception. How do I mitigate this.

Found a post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50349775/laravel-unique-validation-on-multiple-columns) but again it's the same thing I have posted in the question.

Using Laravel 6, and Mysql 8

Answer (score 0):

here you go

```
$request->validate([
   'first_name'=> 'required',
   'active' => 'required',
   'phone' => [
       'required', 
       Rule::unique('delivery_agents')->using(function ($query) use ($request) {
             $query->where('phone', $request->phone)
                 ->where(function ($query) {
                      $query->where('active', 1)
                            ->orWhereNull('active');
}); 
       })
    ],
 ]);
```

Comment: Doesnt work for me, it's the same outcome, There can be multiple non active phone numbers

Comment: why dont you  just check active?

Comment: what you mean ?

Comment: can you explain a little bit clear what should be expected input and output?

Answer (score 0):

Checking not null is enough as you have only 1 and NULL as possible values for `active`

```
'phone' => [
    'required', 
    Rule::unique('delivery_agents')->where(function ($query) use ($request) {
         return $query->where('phone', $request->phone)
               ->whereNotNull('active'); 
    })
],
```

Comment: Indeed try removing `return` maybe?

Comment: still no luck. Let me dig into the Rule class to figure this out