# Set Unique Validation based on Category 1

Tags: octobercms

So I have 2 plugins, say for example `Categories` and `Sub Categories`.

In `Categories` plugin I have 2 records `Category 1` and `Category 2`.

In sub categories I have 2 fields .. 'Select Parent category' which will have a dropdown of `Categories` plugin, having dropdown values as `Category 1` and `Category 2` and another field as `name` in which I can add name of my sub category.

Now I have set a unique validation for my `name` field something like this

```
public $rules = [
        'name' => 'required|unique:technobrave_supportcategories_,name',
    ];
```

This is working fine for me, however, I want unique validation based on my category_id as well ..  IS this possible ?

I am trying this https://stackoverflow.com/a/50350625/6829420 but its not working for me.

Is this possible in OctoberCMS while adding/updating ? Please suggest me

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

@Mittul What does your ID's looke like? I typically have a record id that always auto increments and then will add a unique ID (UID) if need be that is usually manually entered.

Why couldn't this work? Unless I am not fully understanding how you want your relationship to work.

```
public $rules = [
        'id' => 'required|unique:technobrave_supportcategories_,category_id',
        'name' => 'required|unique:technobrave_supportcategories_,name'
    ];
```