# Laravel validation rule with unique and compare with another column

Tags: mysql, laravel, validation, rules

I need a bit of help here

This is my user table. I want to write a laravel validation rule like there should be only one user for one `group_id`. For example, another entry with the name `John` and `group_id=1` should give `The name has already been taken.` error, but should insert `john` with `group_id=2`.

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************          
        id: 1
      name: jhon
  group_id: 1
created_at: 2021-05-31 10:23:42
updated_at: 2021-05-31 10:23:42
*************************** 2. row ***************************
        id: 2
      name: michele
  group_id: 2
created_at: 2021-05-31 10:23:42
updated_at: 2021-05-31 10:23:42
```

I have tried like below, but it is not working. Can anyone help me out?

```
'user.name' => ['required','unique:user,name'.$this->user->id,Rule::unique('user')->where(function ($query) {
    return $query->where('group_id', $this->user->group_id);
})],
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel unique validation on multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50349775/laravel-unique-validation-on-multiple-columns)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write custom validation for that

```
'user.name' => ['required',function ($attribute, $value, $fail) {
                      
   $user= User::where(function ($query){
                            $query->where('name',$this->name);
                            $query->where('group_id',$this->group_id );
                        })->exists();
                        
                    
                       if($user){
                           $fail('User with group already exist');
                       }
                    }],
```

You can ref official documentation

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#using-closures

**Updates**

```
 'user.name' => ['required',function ($attribute, $value, $fail) {
                          
       $user= User::where(function ($query){
                              $query->where('id','!=',$this->user->id)
                                $query->where('name',$this->user->name);
                                $query->where('group_id',$this->user->group_id );
                            })->exists();
                            
                        
                           if($user){
                               $fail('User with group already exist');
                           }
                        }],
```

Comment: Tnx for your quick response and it is working. But I want to ignore the current row for unique validation otherwise it will give an error when I try to update the user. How can I achieve this? Previously it is working and I have used `required|unique:user,name,'.$this->user->id` code

Comment: Sure.Thank you.

Comment: @Rich.glad to here that .it helped you to solve your problem