# Array Validation: unique validation on multiple columns

Tags: laravel, validation, controller, unique-constraint

I am trying to check `unique validation` on three columns `employee_id`,`designation_id`,`station_id` but the data are coming as an `array` which is making my situation unique and different from other SO questions/answers. I already checked few question like below:  [checks unique validation on multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50349775/laravel-unique-validation-on-multiple-columns/50350824)

But in my case, I can't get the value as they are inside an array. I also tried to implement `Custom Rule` or `Request` but in vain. For all the attempts, I am failing to get the `field value` such as `$request->employee_id` as they are inside an `array` for my case. May be I'm not trying it right.

### Controller Code:

```php
    $this->validate($request, [
        'posting.*.employee_id' => 'required,unique: // what to do here ??',
        'posting.*.designation_id' => 'required',
        'posting.*.station_id' => 'required',
        'posting.*.from_date' => 'required|date',
    ]);
```

I am trying to validate uniqueness for both **`create`** and **`update`** `(along with ignore $this->id facility)` but don't know how to implement it here for array. It would be no problem if there was no **`array`**. Any help/suggestion/guide is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by creating a rule i.e UniquePosting so your controller code would look like

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'posting' => ['required'],
    'posting.*' => ['required', new UniquePosting()],
    'posting.*.employee_id' => 'required',
    'posting.*.designation_id' => 'required',
    'posting.*.station_id' => 'required',
    'posting.*.from_date' => 'required|date',
]);
```

Now inside your UniquePosting rule passes function will look like

```
public function passes($attribute, $value) {
    $exists = Posting::where(['employee_id' => $value['employee_id'], 'designation_id' => $value['designation_id'],'station_id' => $value['station_id')->exists();
 return !$exists;
}
```

Add any change if needed, overall that's the concept for testing uniqueness of the whole array.