# Multiple Unique Columns with a Lighthouse Validator Class

Tags: php, laravel, graphql, laravel-8, laravel-lighthouse

**Goal**: Output a custom validation message when attempting to insert a duplicate database record via GraphQL mutation using Laravel Lighthouse.

I've got a unique key constraint being enforced on these multiple fields at the database layer via Laravel migration (`$table->unique(['field_1','field_2','field_3'],'pivot_model_unique');`), and it works, but this outputs an "Internal Server Error" upon a duplicate entry attempt, and that's no good. I want to make it clear to the client via custom error message why the request is denied.

My GraphQL schema:

```graphql
type PivotModel {
  id: ID!
  field_1: ID!
  field_2: ID!
  field_3: ID!
}

type Mutation {
  createPivotModel(pivot_model: CreatePivotModelInput! @spread): PivotModel!
    @create
}

input CreatePivotModelInput @validator(class: "PivotModelInputValidator") {
  field_1: ID!
  field_2: ID!
  field_3: ID!
}
```

My custom Lighthouse Validator class:

```php
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\GraphQL\Validators;

use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;
use Nuwave\Lighthouse\Validation\Validator;

class PivotModelInputValidator extends Validator
{
    /**
     * Return the validation rules.
     *
     * @return array<string, array<mixed>>
     */
    public function rules(): array
    {
        return [
            'field_1' => [
                'filled',
                'numeric',
                'integer',
                Rule::unique('pivot_model')->where(function ($query) {
                    return $query
                        ->where('field_1', $this->arg('field_1'))
                        ->where('field_2', $this->arg('field_2'))
                        ->where('field_3', $this->arg('field_3'));
                }),
            ],
            'field_2' => [
                'filled',
                'numeric',
                'integer',
            ],
            'field_3' => [
                'filled',
                'numeric',
                'integer',
            ],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Return messages for validation errors.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function messages(): array
    {
        return [
            'field_1.unique' => 'duplicate_entry'
        ];
    }
}
```

My request:

```graphql
mutation CreatePivotModel {
  createPivotModel(
    pivot_model: { field_1: 1, field_2: 100, field_3: 1000 }
  ) {
    field_1
    field_2
    field_3
  }
}
```

The response:

```json
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Validation failed for the field [createPivotModel].",
      "extensions": {
        "validation": {
          "pivot_model.field_1": [
            "duplicate_entry"
          ]
        },
        "category": "validation"
      },
      ...
    }
  ]
}
```

This response is output when running that mutation operation regardless if the mutation's arguments are supplied with duplicate or unique data.

It doesn't seem to recognize the closure of `where` clauses in the Lighthouse Validator class to check the other fields, as though it's functionally equivalent to `'field_1' => 'unique:pivot_model'`.

I've tried every answer [in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50349775/laravel-unique-validation-on-multiple-columns) and they don't seem to work.